# Compute the Frequency of bigrams in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to compute and plot the distribution of bigrams frequencies 
First I did generate all possible bigrams which gives 1296 bigrams

then i extract the bigrams from a given file and save them in words1

my question is how to compute the frequency of these 1296 bigrams for the file a.txt?
if there are some bigrams did not appear at all in the file, then their frequencies should be zero

a.txt is any text file

```
clear
clc
%************create bigrams 1296 ***************************************
chars ='1234567890abcdefghijklmonpqrstuvwxyz';
chars1 ='1234567890abcdefghijklmonpqrstuvwxyz';
bigram='';
for i=1:36
for j=1:36

bigram = sprintf('%s%s%s',bigram,chars(i),chars1(j));

end
end
temp1 = regexp(bigram, sprintf('\\w{1,%d}', 1), 'match');
temp2 = cellfun(@(x,y) [x '' y],temp1(1:end-1)', temp1(2:end)','un',0);
bigrams = temp2;
bigrams = unique(bigrams);
bigrams =  rot90(bigrams);
bigram = char(bigrams(1:end));
all_bigrams_len = length(bigrams);
clear temp temp1 temp2 i j chars1 chars;

%****** 1. Cleaning Data ******************************
collection = fileread('e:\a.txt');
collection = regexprep(collection,'<.*?>','');
collection = lower(collection);
collection = regexprep(collection,'\W','');
collection = strtrim(regexprep(collection,'\s*',''));

%*******************************************************

temp = regexp(collection, sprintf('\\w{1,%d}', 1), 'match');
temp2 = cellfun(@(x,y) [x '' y],temp(1:end-1)', temp(2:end)','un',0);
words1 = rot90(temp2);

%*******************************************************
words1_len = length(words1);
vocab1 = unique(words1);
vocab_len1 = length(vocab1);
[vocab1,void1,index1] = unique(words1);
frequencies1 = hist(index1,vocab_len1);
```

Comment: Have you tried making a histogram?

Comment: I did but I always get wrong results...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### I. Character counting problem for a string

`bsxfun` based solution for counting characters -

```
counts = sum(bsxfun(@eq,[string1-0]',65:90))
```

Output -

```
counts =

    2     0     0     0     0     2     0     1     0     0 ....
```

If you would like to get a tabulate output of counts against each letter -

```
out = [cellstr(['A':'Z']') num2cell(counts)']
```

Output -

```
out = 
    'A'    [2]
    'B'    [0]
    'C'    [0]
    'D'    [0]
    'E'    [0]
    'F'    [2]
    'G'    [0]
    'H'    [1]
    'I'    [0]

....
```

Please note that this was a case-sensitive counting for upper-case letters.

For a lower-case letter counting, use this edit to this earlier code -

```
counts = sum(bsxfun(@eq,[string1-0]',97:122))
```

For a case insensitive counting, use this -

```
counts = sum(bsxfun(@eq,[upper(string1)-0]',65:90))
```

---

### II. Bigram counting case

Let us suppose that you have all the possible bigrams saved in a 1D cell array `bigrams1` and the incoming bigrams from the file are saved into another cell array `words1`. Let us also assume certain values in them for demonstration -

```
bigrams1 = {
    'ar';
    'de';
    'c3';
    'd1';
    'ry';
    't1';
    'p1'}

words1 = {
    'de';
    'c3';
    'd1';
    'r9';
    'yy';
    'de';
    'ry';
    'de';
    'dd';
    'd1'}
```

Now, you can get the counts of the bigrams from `words1` that are present in `bigrams1` with this code -

```
[~,~,ind] = unique(vertcat(bigrams1,words1));
bigrams_lb = ind(1:numel(bigrams1)); %// label bigrams1
words1_lb = ind(numel(bigrams1)+1:end);  %// label words1
counts = sum(bsxfun(@eq,bigrams_lb,words1_lb'),2)
out = [bigrams1 num2cell(counts)]
```

The output on code run is -

```
out = 
    'ar'    [0]
    'de'    [3]
    'c3'    [1]
    'd1'    [2]
    'ry'    [1]
    't1'    [0]
    'p1'    [0]
```

The result shows that - First element `ar` from the list of all possible bigrams has no find in `words1` ; second element `de` has three occurrences in `words1` and so on.

Comment: in my code, first i am extracting all the possible bigrams, then i extract all bigrams in the a.txt file now, some of the bigrams do not exist in the a.txt which means their frequencies are zero. my code always compare these bigrams against the unique set of bigrams in the a.txt itself and not against the all bigrams.

Comment: @Aabualia Please update your question a small minimal working code for the bigrams detailing the input and the expected output.

Comment: i thought these some rules and i must do that :)

Answer (score 2):

Hey similar to Dennis solution you can just use `histc()`

```
string1 = 'ASHRAFF'
histc(string1,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
```

this checks the number of entries in the bins defined by the string `'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'` which is hopefully the alphabet (just wrote it fast so no garantee). The result is:

```
  Columns 1 through 21

     2     0     0     0     0     2     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0

  Columns 22 through 26

     0     0     0     0     0
```

Just a little modification of my solution:

```
string1 = 'ASHRAFF'
alphabet1='A':'Z'; %%// as stated by Oleg Komarov
data=histc(string1,alphabet1);
results=cell(2,26);
for k=1:26
    results{1,k}= alphabet1(k);
    results{2,k}= data(k);
end
```

If you look at `results` now you can easily check rather it works or not :D

Comment: You can also do `'A':'Z'` to create the ASCII alphabet

Answer (score 1):

This answer creates all bigrams, loads in the file does a little cleanup, ans then uses a combination of `unique` and `histc` to count the rows

### Generate all Bigrams

note the order here is important as unique will sort the array so this way it is created presorted so the output matches expectation;

```
[y,x] = ndgrid(['0':'9','a':'z']);
allBigrams = [x(:),y(:)];
```

### Read The File

this removes capitalisation and just pulls out any 0-9 or a-z character then creates a column vector of these

```
fileText = lower(fileread('d:\loremipsum.txt'));
cleanText = regexp(fileText,'([a-z0-9])','tokens');
cleanText = cell2mat(vertcat(cleanText{:}));
```

create bigrams from file by shifting by one and concatenating

```
fileBigrams = [cleanText(1:end-1),cleanText(2:end)];
```

### Get Counts

the set of all bigrams is added to our set (so the values are created for all possible). Then a value ∈{1,2,...,1296} is assigned to each unique row using `unique`'s 3rd output. Counts are then created with `histc` with the bins equal to the set of values from `unique`'s output, 1 is subtracted from each bin to remove the complete set bigrams we added

```
[~,~,c] = unique([fileBigrams;allBigrams],'rows');
counts = histc(c,1:1296)-1;
```

### Display

to view counts against text

```
[allBigrams, counts+'0']
```

or for something potentially more useful...

```
[sortedCounts,sortInd] = sort(counts,'descend');
[allBigrams(sortInd,:), sortedCounts+'0']


ans =

or9
at8
re8
in7
ol7
te7
do6 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Did not look into the entire code fragment, but from the example at the top of your question, I think you are looking to make a histogram:

```
string1 = 'ASHRAFF'
nr = histc(string1,'A':'Z')
```

Will give you:

```
 2     0     0     0     0     2     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

(Got a working solution with `hist`, but as @The Minion shows `histc` is more easy to use here.)

Note that this solution only deals with upper case letters.

You may want to do something like so if you want to put lower case letters in their correct bin:

```
string1 = 'ASHRAFF'
nr = histc(upper(string1),'A':'Z')
```

Or if you want them to be shown separately:

```
string1 = 'ASHRaFf'
nr = histc(upper(string1),['a':'z' 'A':'Z'])
```

Comment: Hmm coming to think of it, this may fail if the letters are not equally spaced, will edit.

Comment: Could you elaborate those values `[2 3 0 0 2]`? Because they can neither be the numbers of A,F,H,R,S (Because H,R obviously should have a 1) nor can it be the full alphabet (because there is no B in that string). Also the OP asked for a list of all letters including those not present in the string. Mind editing your answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
bi_freq1 = zeros(1,all_bigrams_len);
for k=1: vocab_len1
 for i=1:all_bigrams_len
  if  char(vocab1(k)) == char(bigrams(i))
       bi_freq1(i) = frequencies1(k);
  end
 end
end
```